# Need help with the maths book name with the question?

Tags: book-recommendation

I am sorry but being a newbie to Abstract Algebra, got interested in a question asked online about permutations of a group. I wanted to know the name of the book, but it seems the googling would not help. The image for the question being asked is at: https://ibb.co/e3aNNb

I would be highly thankful as the question seems nice for starting the topic for a beginner, and such question is not seen till now in any other book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is from *A Book of Abstract Algebra* (second edition) by Charles C Pinter.
See [Google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZAo_AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=%22list+the+symmetries+of+each+of+the+following+polynomials%22&source=bl&ots=gLN5bzD2uO&sig=9iCDZ46Ojcy-nfIdpCju9tvo68I&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22list%20the%20symmetries%20of%20each%20of%20the%20following%20polynomials%22&f=false).